# ClassNotFoundException when deploying JBPM application to JBoss

Tags: java, drools, jboss6.x, jbpm

I have the following problem with JBoss EAP 6.2 (configured in cluster mode) related to the deployment of my web application.

My web app is an war file that contains: processes defined with JBPM2 and REST services for start process, retrieving tasks, etc.

I use JBPM 6.0.1.Final library to definiton and access at my processes and tasks.

The architecture is based on Spring that create an org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManager object:

```
     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
            if (runtimeManager == null) {
                RuntimeEnvironment environment = (RuntimeEnvironment) RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.getDefault()
                        .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                        .userGroupCallback(userGroupCallback)
                        .addAsset(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("test.bpmn2"), ResourceType.BPMN2)
                        .get();
```

((SimpleRegisterableItemsFactory)environment.getRegisterableItemsFactory()).addWorkItemHandler("Log", SystemOutWorkItemHandler.class);
                   runtimeManager = org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(environment);
                }
            }

But when I deploy my web-app the line code with underline, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/example]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 181) JBWEB000289: Servlet example threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.audit.WorkingMemoryLogger from [Module "deployment.example.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55] 
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]

        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]

        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory.getProcessEventListeners(DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory.java:77) [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]

        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.AbstractRuntimeManager.registerItems(AbstractRuntimeManager.java:85) [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]

        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SingletonRuntimeManager.init(SingletonRuntimeManager.java:99) [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]

        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:71) [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]

        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:62) [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
```

But with JBoss EAP 6.2 configured in standalone mode, all works correctly.

Someone can help me kindly.

Regards